# How do you create a loop that assesses if the number is greater than 5. The list [7,2,9,3,1,10,8,6,4,5]?

Tags: python, loop

```
x = [7,2,9,3,1,10,8,6,4,5]
for number in x:
      if x > 5:
       print x
```

This is all I got. New to python.  The output just gives me the list again

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please edit your question to indicate how this is related to GIS? Otherwise, this is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: There appears to be no GIS component to your pure Python question that would be better researched/asked at [so].

Answer (score 2):

One of the most efficient Python data structures for manipulating list data is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). For example:

```
numbers = [7,2,9,3,1,10,8,6,4,5]

print [x for x in numbers if x > 5]
```

---

```
>>> 
[7, 9, 10, 8, 6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = [7,2,9,3,1,10,8,6,4,5]
for number in x:
    if number > 5:
        print number
```

`number` is assigned to each value of the array `x`, one after another (it iterates over `x`).  BTW, proper indents in Python are very important since code blocks are indicated by how deeply each line is indented.